# How large is the Dominion?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Is there any evidence that speaks to the size of the Dominion in a quantifiable number of changelings? Does the entire liquid surface of Odo's homeworld consist of changelings, or only a portion of it?

Comment: Are you talking about the Dominion, or about the Founders' home planet? The Founders (as far as we know) live on only one planet, but the Dominion they rule has many many planets and species.

Comment: @Algernon_Asimov It's Rondo, I don't think we'll be getting any clarification..

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I don't know who's who, or recognise personalities.

Comment: Given the Great Link, it’s unclear to what extent “individual” changelings actually exist.

Answer (score 7):

The question doesn't make sense from the perspective of the Changelings. There are not really distinct consciousnesses. From *Behind The Lines*:

> ODO: You haven't told me your name.
>
> FOUNDER: What use would I have for a name?
>
> ODO: To differentiate yourself from the others.
>
> FOUNDER: I don't.
>
> ODO: But you are a separate being, aren't you?
>
> FOUNDER: In a sense.
>
> ODO: When you return to the Link, what will happen to the entity I'm talking to right now?
>
> FOUNDER: The drop becomes the ocean.
>
> ODO: And if you choose to take solid form again?
>
> FOUNDER: The ocean becomes a drop.
>
> ODO: Ah, yes. I think I'm beginning to understand.
>
> FOUNDER: Then you can answer your own question. How many of us are there?
>
> ODO: One. And many. It depends on how you look at it.
>
> FOUNDER: Very good. You are beginning to understand. But there's so much you don't know.

Answer (score 7):

As Algernon_Asimov has pointed out in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/how-large-is-the-dominion/144824#comment40266_22022), the Dominion actually consists of *two* distinct parts;

- **The Dominion itself**, an interstellar empire largely controlled by the Vorta and their Jem'Hadar henchmen.
- **The (hidden) world of the 'Founders of the Dominion'**, populated by changelings who're pulling all the strings from the shadows.

The Dominion proper covers an area roughly the same size as the Romulan Star Empire, some 36 billion cubic light years and encompassing hundreds, if not thousands of inhabited planets, many of which (we learn from the [Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) factbook) have populations into their billions. This includes the homeworlds of the Dosi (1.5Bn) and the Karemma (4.5Bn).

[image]

With regard to the population of the Founder's World, this is rather easier to answer. The number of changelings is precisely **one.** They form an homogeneous hive-mind in their liquid state and periodically 'bud off' individuals when they want to communicate with solids, explore the galaxy or conduct espionage. When those tasks are completed, the buds return to the "great link" where their knowledge is shared.